# Installing Windows XP sp2 on a system with an i5 processor

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, cpu

I want to install Windows XP service pack 2 on my computer which is powered by an Intel Core i5 processor. I must have Windows XP sp2 because of certain software I must run that do not support other OSes.

Is there a way that I could install XP sp2 in a virtual machine? Could someone tell me how?

Comment: You will need a bit more detail. Is there an OS on teh system now and you want to run a virtual machine? Doe steh important software need to access any special hardware? Say PCCARD devices?

Comment: I have done XP virtualised in win7, For ME it was a very large waste of my time and effort.  I could boot to Real XP on my other disk. The whole virtual package installed beautifully, but it was "virtual" and slow.  I would only ever do that again, if I needed to sandbox, or run a very minor simple program. for any XP program for ME it has to be real.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing about the Intel Core i5 processors that should prevent you from installing Windows XP on a system powered by it.

I'm writing this answer on a computer powered by the i3 processor running Windows XP sp3.

If this is not the answer to your true question, please rephrase your question to clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 2):

*Is there a way that I could install XP sp2 in a virtual machine?*: yes, certainly.

- Download and install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org)
- (optional) Create an ISO image from your XP SP2 cd
- Create a new VM with VirtualBox and use real CD (or ISO you just created, for better performances and because you won't need to insert CD after some update) to start installation there
- Install your software, hoping it's not protected not to run on virtual machines...

I think you will do everything in an hour or less!!